# Eurostat metadata via API

Tags: data-request, api, europe, rest

Eurostat, the agency managing statistics related to the European Union, has an API for accessing its statistics. The data is accessed in different forms e.g. the actual dataset/observations and data structures (the available filters for a dataset). Whilst I have been able to access these via a JSON/XML REST API, I am led to believe that you can also access metadata about a statistic, meaning descriptive information such as metric description, collection method etc. Here is an example of this type of information that Eurostat provides on the web:

https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/en/gov_10dd_sgd_esms.htm

The question is whether there is a REST (either XML or JSON) API to access this metadata information. And if so what is the query syntax?

I have spent the last weeks reading any guides available by Eurostat and also from SDMX, the standard used by Eurostat to collect and store the data but I can't figure out how to access the metadata.